# Space out and replace radio buttons with images in boostrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to do two different things with a set of radio buttons.

```
<div id="timeSpanForm">
    <input type="radio" id="timeSpan" name="timeSpan" value="0">0-2år
    <input type="radio" id="timeSpan" name="timeSpan" value="2">2-10 år
    <input type="radio" id="timeSpan" name="timeSpan" value="10">10+ år                    
</div>
```

1. I want to replace the radio button circle with an image that displays another image when checked.
2. I want to space out the radio buttons evenly.

So my question is how to do this in general but then also specifically if there is a special boostrap way to do it, since i have to work in bootstrap without too much experience. I have tried googling but not found anything specific. Maybe i just dont get the right search terms.

Im using bootstrap.

Comment: Not sure about question #1 but for justifying, take a look at Bootstrap docs here: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav-justified (you can destyle the navs so they just look like text)

Comment: @RachelS. Thanks for your time! But im not really sure how this would help.

Comment: @Lautaro this would justify your radio inputs and keep them evenly spaced apart.

Comment: @RachelS Thanks! That did it. I couldnt rap my head on how to use it since its not nav items. But i got it. Cheers!

Comment: @RachelS
Make it into an answer so i can tag it as correct.

Comment: I can't anymore but you can vote my comment up ;)